# Wordpress: move sidebar menu to the bottom

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Could anybody please suggest me a way to move the sidebar menu on this website to the bottom of the page: http://rencontresduvietnam.org/conferences/2016/search-for-life/ ?

I have played with CSS for a while but haven't got expected results :(

Thank you in advance!

**Update**

I tried the following as suggested by @Souljacker:

```
.sidebar-container {
    position: static!important;
}
```

and as suggested by @c-travel:

```
.site-main .sidebar-container {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0px!important;
}
```

The sidebar was moved to the bottom but it's ugly:

[image]

Is there a way to limit it to the end of the text?
Thanks.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: @j08691: Yes I'm aware of what you say but I don't have any idea on what code to put in the answer (any suggestions?), because to find a solution we need to inspect the page anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You have couple of options.

Create the hook for the menu.

Change the menu in the template.

If you change it at your template files (the easiest) you have to go to your theme's folder and find for

```
sidebar.php
```

There must be the code that enables your menu to show up on your sidebar...

Mostly themes have the parts isolated, and the bottom should be on the file footer.php , if you are looking to insert it at the footer part, then you can just paste the code there... should work

Comment: Thanks, @jpganz18. I will give it a try if I cannot find simpler solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
.sidebar-container {
    position: static;
}
```

This will get it back to the normal code flow.

Comment: Thanks, Souljacker. This actually moved the sidebar to the bottom but it's ugly. Could you please see my update?